# ANTLR Making Negative Test Cases

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, lexer

I'm new to ANTLR and am trying to understand how to do some things with it.  I need it to throw an error when a statement is missing things, like a semicolon or an end bracket.  It's been called negative test cases by the problem set that I'm working through.

For example, the below code returns true, which is correct.

```
val program = """
1 + 2;
"""

recognize(program)
```

However, this code also returns true, despite it missing the semicolon at the end.  It should return false ([PARSER error at line=1]: missing ';' at '').

```
val program = """
1 + 2
""".trimIndent()

recognize(program)
```

The grammar is as follows:

```
program: (expression ';')* | EOF;

expression: INT PLUS INT | OPENBRAC INT PLUS INT CLOSEBRAC | QUOTE IDENT QUOTE PLUS QUOTE IDENT QUOTE;

IDENT: [A-Za-z0-9]+;
INT: [-][0-9]+ | ('0'..'9')+;
PLUS: '+';
OPENBRAC: '(';
CLOSEBRAC: ')';
QUOTE: '"';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
program: (expression ';')* | EOF;
```

This means a program can either be zero or more instances of `expression ';'` followed by whatever else is in the input stream *or* it can be empty. Since `(expression ';')*` can already match the empty input by itself, the `| EOF` is just redundant.

What you want is `program: (expression ';')* EOF`, which means that a program consists of zero or more instances of `expression ';'`, *followed by* the end of input, meaning there must be nothing left in the input afterwards.

Comment: I changed that line and it now returns false for both of the test statements that I put above

Comment: @Stacey You're not allowing any spaces or line breaks in the input, so before the change it actually applied `(expression ';')*` zero times and then left everything in the input stream.

Comment: @sepp2k The EOF is not reduntant, even with that loop which can match nothing. It makes sure that `program` succeeds only if the entire input can be matched by `(expression ';')*`. As it is now it would also succeed for anything that would not match `(expression ';')*`. Hence `|` should be removed.

Comment: @MikeLischke Please re-read my answer, I said the same thing you did.

Comment: Yes, right, only got half of the message, sorry.